# Multistore Switch based on url

Tags: magento2, multistore

I want to change the store of my magento website based on the url.
For example if I open up a URL that exists on my secondary store I get a 404 if it's not the first time entering the website.
Basically I think I would need an observer to check where that url is available and switch the store accordingly.
Obviously the urls will be unique.
Thanks and I hope someone can help me or give me a direction as I have looked for modules and other info but all I could find was geoip redirection.

Comment: Please, I have faced the same issue. Whats the solution?

Answer (score 0):

follow these tutorial they have explained it nicely.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-and-configure-multistore-magento-2/

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html

https://meetanshi.com/blog/setup-magento-2-multi-store/

Comment: Thanks I have managed to do it with .htaccess in the end.